# Joomla - PHP altering mySQL statement in model

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm having a syntax issue with this bit of code:

```
$query = "SELECT *
        FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__mls')."
        WHERE 1=1"
            . if ($zip != null)
                { AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTZIP')." = ".$db->quote($zip)."}
            . if ($city != null)
                { AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTCITY')." = '".$db->quote($city)."'}
            . if ($bdrms != null)
                { AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTBDRMS')." >= ".$db->quote($bdrms)."}
            . if ($bths != null)
                { AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTBATHS')." >= ".$db->quote($bths)."}
            . if ($lprice != null)
                { AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTLISTPRC')." BETWEEN ".$db->quote($lprice)." AND ".$db->quote($hprice)."} 
        ";"
    ;
```

First string `"` starts the query statement, second `"` layer assigns the table, when the `WHERE` statement, then it gets tricky.  All the `if` statements are messing with me. I feel like that's where a `"` is getting misplaced or missing.

Comment: note the color highlighting in the display here. You're missing a `"` before everything single `AND`. you cannot concatenate `if` tests like that either. this code is utterly broken.

Comment: what error is the error log displaying?

Comment: But doesn't the `"` after `WHERE 1=1"` take care of that sytax?

Comment: no. it doesn't. if() is a language construct. it's not a function with a return value. you **CANNOT** concetentation if()'s like that. and remember that in php `AND` is a boolean operator, with a slightly lower precedence than `||`. you're doing `{ || ... }`, which is a flat out syntax error.

Comment: If you use the API you can have two where statements and put the second one inside an if block.

$query->where('1 = 1', AND): //assuming that makes sense
if (whatever)
{
   $query->where (.$db->nameQuote('MSTZIP')." = ".$db->quote($zip)):
}
if (whateverelse)
{
  $query->where($db->nameQuote('MSTCITY')." = '".$db->quote($city));
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utterly broken beyond belief. Try something more like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $db->nameQuote('#__mls') . " WHERE 1=1";
$clauses = array();
if ($zip != null) {
   $clauses[] = $db->nameQuote('MSTZIP') . " = " . $db->quote($zip);
}
if (etc...) {
   ... 
}
$query .= implode(' AND ', $clauses);
echo $query;
```

Comment: I don't know what you just did, but it looks amazing.

Comment: It looks good, but it doesn't apply the variables.  My queries come up blank.  If I don't apply any var/arguments in the URL, it will display everything.  Once I add var/arguments, nothing shows up.

Comment: do you have error checking on the queries? never assume they succeeded.

Comment: As far as the values being there, yeah, they're there.  I mean, since this was altered, I don't know if it changed the way the array was configured and so I'll have to go back and adjust my view/tmpl. What about the `$query.= implide(' AND ', $clauses);` statement?

Also, will the `if` statement read `zip` where `index.php?zip=&city=chicago` as a null value?

Comment: I'm not sure this is building the array how I wanted it. And believe me, I'm not being ungrateful.  I'm just trying to sort through what you did.

Comment: So, instead of building a table, I did a var dump.  When I run the URL with no arguments, it dumps all the data.  When I put in a argument, it comes back null.  [here](http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=list&zip=62002)

Answer (score 1):

Before every `AND` you are missing `"` , you need to build your query in different manner (please double check every `'` I am sure I missed few somewhere)

```
   $query = "SELECT *
    FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__mls')."
     WHERE 1=1";
         if ($zip != null)
             { $query .= " AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTZIP')." = '".$db->quote($zip)."'";}
         if ($city != null)
              {$query .= " AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTCITY')." = '".$db->quote($city)."'";}

          if ($bdrms != null)
             {$query .= " AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTBDRMS')." >= '".$db->quote($bdrms)."'";}
        if ($bths != null)
            {$query .= " AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTBATHS')." >= '".$db->quote($bths)."'";}
         if ($lprice != null)
             {$query .= " AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTLISTPRC')." BETWEEN '".$db->quote($lprice)." AND ".$db->quote($hprice).";} 

;
```